# How to set custom color in AddTimeLine

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I am trying to create a time line plot using `leaflet` and `leaftime` packages. I want to set custom color in `addTimeline` to specify each point to his groups,  as follows:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaftime)
library(geojsonio)

power_d <- data.frame(
  "Latitude" = c(
    33.515556, 38.060556, 47.903056, 49.71, 49.041667, 31.934167,
    54.140586, 54.140586, 48.494444, 48.494444
  ),
  "Longitude" = c(
    129.837222, -77.789444, 7.563056, 8.415278, 9.175, -82.343889,
    13.664422, 13.664422, 17.681944, 17.681944
  ),
  "start" = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 10),
  "end" = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 10) + 1,
color_temp=rep(c("red","blue","green"),len=10)
)

power_geo <- geojsonio::geojson_json(power_d ,lat="Latitude",lon="Longitude")

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(44.0665,23.74667,2) %>%
  addTimeline(data = power_geo,
  timelineOpts = timelineOptions(
      styleOptions = styleOptions(
    radius = 5,     
    color=color_temp,
    fillColor = color_temp,
    fillOpacity = 1
      )
    )
)
```

Unfortunately I got following error:

> Error in lapply(x, f) : object 'color_temp' not found

I also try replacing `color_temp` with `power_d$color_temp`, the code run without error, but the color of points do not change. The color arguments not work in above code, why? and how to fix it?

Comment: It seems you can't pass a vector of colour like this but check the third last example in `addTimeline` but change the relevant line to `color: data.properties.color_temp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem as if you can pass a vector of colours with the standard `styleOptions`, however, an example from the help page for `?addTimeline` show how you can add colours based on the data using a little JavaScript (which thankfully is provided in the example).

Using the example that starts "*# to style each point differently based on the data*" you need to change it slightly to point to your colour vector e.g. change `data.properties.color` to `data.properties.color_temp`. Running the code below leads to

[image]

```
# code
leaflet(power_geo) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(44.0665,23.74667,2) %>%
  addTimeline(
    timelineOpts = timelineOptions(
      styleOptions = NULL, 
      pointToLayer = htmlwidgets::JS(
"
function(data, latlng) {
  return L.circleMarker(
    latlng,
    {
      radius: 25,
      color: data.properties.color_temp,
      fillColor: data.properties.color_temp,
      fillOpacity: 1
    }
  );
}
"
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: It works! In this case how to set popup? I think it should pass ' L.circleMarker'? for example if we want to pass color_temp and further information How to do it?

Comment: I found it! '.bindPopup()' can pass popup!

Comment: I want to customize date in the above code. How to do it? I try in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242487/how-to-customize-date-in-leaflet

Comment: Why in the code, when we press forward (or backward) button, we have current time point and next time point?